# Why does the highlighted text color in Xcode's Project Navigator sometimes switch to white with a blue shadow?

Tags: xcode

Normally a selected item in Xcode's Project Navigator is indicated by a blue bar behind the item. However, sometimes for no apparent reason this changes to white text with a kind of very light blue drop shadow and no background color change. Does anyone know why this occurs  or how to prevent it? To fix it I always just have to restart Xcode.

[image: Xcode's Project Navigator]

I'm using Xcode 7.2.1 (7C1002) on an OSX El Capitan 10.11.3 machine.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm having this issue as well. I suspect it may be a graphical bug.

Comment: Have you discovered any way of getting it back to normal without restarting XCode?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I find that clicking around for a bit has a chance of solving the problem, but I may be mistaken

Comment: Using 7.3.1. Same problem. ggwp Apple.

Comment: This has been happening to me since Xcode 6, and it is still a problem in Xcode 8. Selecting a different tab in the navigator (such as Find) and then going back to the Project tab seems to temporarily resolve the issue, but I haven't been able to figure out what causes it or how to permanently resolve it.

Comment: I just discovered that resizing the navigator pane also appears to resolve the problem (again, just temporarily).

Answer (score 6):

It's just a bug which happens sometimes in Xcode, still happening in 8.1.

You don't have to restart to fix it, you can just hide and show the navigator by clicking this button twice:

[image]

Comment: Also happening with me on 8.1. Usually it happens after selecting a storyboard file.

Comment: @DielsonSales if you can reproduce it you should file a bug report with Apple

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue with Xcode 7 (all versions). I have to relaunch the Xcode project to correct the highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using multiple tabs. I just closed all the tabs leaving only one opened. 
It's a very dangerous bug, it reverted my info.plist file to an older version.

Answer (score -1):

This happens if you lower your brightness in the display...increase it and it will be fixed...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: As far as I know I have not lowered the brightness.